# Python share name printer

Tags: python, share, zebra-printers

I developed a Python script (2.6) under Linux.

I run this script from a Windows machine that is in the network.

I shared the printer connected via USB to the Windows computer.

I wish I retrieve the share name of the printer via my script.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/558133/1129194

Comment: How are you sharing the printer? From the Linux computer? Using CUPS (IPP) or Samba?

Comment: Yes, my printer is recognized by CUPS. I shared via samba option in CUPS. I would have given the same name as the share name in windows.
My goal is to be able to print on the printer execute my script knowing that I have 5 PC with 5 printers connected and shared.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This solution assumes that you have a [CUPS](http://www.cups.org/) server running on the Linux box and the `pycups` package also available on your *Python* environment (*Debian/Ubuntu*: `apt-get install python-cups`, *Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS*: `yum install python-cups`, or installed from [source](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycups/): more complicated because it depends on `libcups` development files availability for successful compilation.).

Add the remote *Windows* printers to the *Linux* box *CUPS* server. This will make the printers locally accessible to the *Python* script running on *Linux*.

Then use the [pycups](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycups/) package to interact with the printers ([documentation](http://packages.python.org/pycups/)). For example to list the printers installed in the local *CUPS* server and print a file to one of the installed printers:

```
import cups

conn = cups.Connection ()

# get printers available in the local CUPS server
printers = conn.getPrinters ()
for printer in printers:
    print printer, printers[printer]["device-uri"]

# get the first key from the printers dictionary as a sample printer name
printer_name = printers.keys()[0]
conn.printFile(printer_name, 'test_file_name.raw', 'job title', {})
```

Comment: Hi, my script is executed in linux machine, not in windows machine. It is execute via http in windows machine. I saw pywin32 but this module is only for Python under Windows. I want exactly what pywin32 but linux.

Comment: So, to clarify: you have printers installed on Windows machines shared from Windows and you want to print to those printers from Linux. Is that it?

Comment: Try a package version of the module first, instead of trying to compile from source. Which Linux distribution are you using? If it is Debian/Ubuntu you just need to do: `apt-get install python-cups`. Red Hat/CentOS/Fedora: `yum install python-cups`. If you do need to compile the module from source you need to have the CUPS development package installed (i.e CUPS header files and development libraries).

Comment: I get an error when compiling pycups `cupsmodule.c:23: fatal error: cups/cups.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type compilation terminated. error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: I already installed python-cups in my Ubuntu distribution and I executed the comande `sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: ok I installed package `libcups2-dev` and compilation well done

Comment: Ok i'm error `IPPError: (1042, 'client-error-document-access-error')`